# Adding Github repo to my resume

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, resume, software-development, intellectual-property

Besides repos for basic school projects, I have one private Git repository for an app I'm making with several friends.

That repository contains code that utilizes much more advanced programming concepts, than those that are taught in sophomore level class.

My concern about sharing this repository, however, is the fact that the app is still under development and my group members don't want the code to get out so that no one steals our idea.

Would sharing this repository with a specific employer be too risky?

Comment: I suppose that repo is private otherwise there is no problem in sharing it

Comment: @MichaelGlu Please clarify whether it's a public or private repository. If it's public, anybody can steal your idea by looking at it.

Comment: You'll have to negotiate this with your group members. Do you even have a contract with them? What happens if the partnership doesn't go as planned? You should really have a contract. And if you're the only programmer in the group, you should have a lot of leverage in determining what goes in that contract if they want you to continue to work on the project with them.

Answer (score 3):

> Would sharing this repository with a specific employer be too risky?

Since your group members don't want this shared, then don't.

It might not be a big risk to you, but you risk your friendships within your group. Imagine how your friends will feel about you if the code is somehow stolen due to your actions.

Respect the wishes of your friends.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues.

1) Does the employer even care. Many don't. They realize that many programmers are unable to show the code they have developed. They may never check the site.

2) Your partners may not want to have the code shared.

The 2nd one could be a red flag if a potential employer realizes that you exposed the code without the permission of the rest of the team. They might worry that you will do the same thing with their proprietary code.

Unless everybody agrees to expose the code, then  exposing the code is too risky.